Problems with mini app tg hash verification
I have a problem with data hashing. Even though the input data remains the same, the resulting hash is different. Could you help me figure this out?
function checkTelegramAuthorization(initDataString, botToken) {
  if (typeof botToken !== 'string' || !botToken) {
    console.error('Invalid botToken: Expected a non-empty string.');
    return null;
  }

  if (typeof initDataString !== 'string' || !initDataString) {
    console.error('Invalid initDataString: Expected a non-empty string.');
    return null;
  }

  try {
    const initData = new URLSearchParams(initDataString);
    const receivedHash = initData.get('hash');
    initData.delete('hash');

    const dataCheckString = [...initData.entries()]
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
      .sort()
      .join('\n');

    console.log(initData)
    console.log(dataCheckString)

    const computedHash = crypto
      .createHmac('sha256', botToken)
      .update(dataCheckString)
      .digest('hex');


    return computedHash === receivedHash ? Object.fromEntries(initData) : null;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error verifying Telegram authorization:', err);
    return null;
  }
}

